# How to use not equal to filter in Zend

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am very new to Zend.

I know I can use this way to filter my table:

```php
$users = $this->getEntityManager()
         ->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\User')
         ->findBy(array('age' => 20, 'surname' => 'foo'));
```

This will give me only those users who has age 20 and surname as foo.

**However I want to have filter where it gives me user who has age 20 and surname is `not foo`.**

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine does not provide a `NOT` in their built in `find*` methods. You have to built your own.

1. Create custom Repository

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository; //maybe a slightly different path

class CustomRepo extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findByAgeNotSurname($age, $surname)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

        return $qb->where('u.age = :age')
            ->andWhere('u.surname != :surname')
            ->setParameters(array('age' => $age, 'surname' => $surname))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

2. Add Repository to Entity

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Namespace\To\CustomRepo")
 */
class Entity
```

Code is not tested but should work.

Comment: Thanks, but what do I assign to this variable - `$em`? Is it `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();`?

Comment: Ah sry updated my code to use bit shorter (and correct) syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$users = $this->getEntityManager()
         ->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\User')
         ->findBy(array('age' => 20, 'surname !=' => 'foo'));
```